# Google Maps v3 API - When is it safe to start?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Most of the examples online that load the Google Maps API wait for the window `load` event to actually create a map, ie:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKeyHere&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
  ,mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp

My question is, is it necessary to wait for the window load event? In particular, would a DOMContentReady handler be sufficient? My experience shows that it ordinarily is, but every now and then I get strange errors from my users such as `google.maps.MapTypeId is undefined` in my initialization function.

Comment: Google uses `window.load` in their API documentation. I would stick with that, particularly if you're getting errors when you change it to something else.

Comment: Does that mean you can't even use `script` tags to load other scripts that depend on Google Maps?

Comment: That would have been useful info to have in the question. What do the other scripts do?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for waiting for the load event is that the div containing the map needs to have a size before you initialize the map object.

If you initialize the google.maps.Map before the div containing it has a size the API will get a zero size for that element and will load the map with the center in the upper left corner.  There has been lots (and lots) of instances of people encountering that issue.

That can be addressed by triggering the google.maps.Map resize event on the map object after the load event fires.